# JSON not working with LIRC

Tags: python, python-3, lirc

I have the following script which is meant to write/read a json file. The problem is it will only write/read the file from the command line and not when using a remote via LIRC.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep
import json

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

GPIO.setup(22,GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(19,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(21,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(23,GPIO.OUT)

abort = False
counter = 0

# read config
try:
    with open('config.json') as readfile:
        data = json.load(readfile)
    if data['lastrun'] == 'up':
        print('blind is already up')
        abort = True
except:
    pass

data = {'lastrun': 'up'}

if abort:
    quit()

# write config
with open('config.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile, sort_keys=True, indent=4)

print('blind up')
GPIO.output(19,GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.output(21,GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(23,GPIO.HIGH)

while True:
        input_state = GPIO.input(22)
        if input_state == False:
                counter = counter + 1
                print counter
                if counter == 13:
                        GPIO.output(23,GPIO.LOW)
                        exit()
                        GPIO.cleanup()  
                sleep (0.3)
```

This is the entry in the lircrc file

```
begin
    button = KEY_4
    prog = irexec
    config = sudo python /home/pi/up.py
end
```

Comment: @jsotola - thanks. I have now edited the question with details of the lircrc entry whcih calls the script

Comment: If your using sudo - it will be run as root user, so I would suggest adding the full path to the config.json file ie '/home/pi/config.json'

Comment: @CoderMike You should make your comment an answer so *Nick* can accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Question was answered by @CoderMike in comments:

> If you're using sudo - it will be run as root user, so I would suggest adding the full path to the config.json file ie '/home/pi/config.json'